# CSS for table scroll not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page in which there is a table which populates data from a database table and I am trying to restrict the size of the table by placing it in a div like in the following

```
<div id="scrollablebody">

<table class="clientTable">

    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Term</th>              
            <th colspan="3">Actions</th>    
        </tr>    
    </thead>

    <!--ko foreach: products-->

    <tr>
            <td  class="clientproductHeader" data-bind="text: $data">

            </td>
         <td  class="clientproductHeader" colspan="13"></td>
        </tr>


    <tbody  data-bind="foreach: ko.observableArray($root.datainput()).extendsdistinct('Product').index.Product()[$data]">             


        <tr data-bind="template: { name: $root.displayMode, data: $data }"></tr>

    </tbody>
    <!--/ko-->

</table>

    </div>
```

CSS for div

```
 #scrollablebody{height:500px;overflow-y:auto;width:100%;}
```

But for some reasons the text in tbody is occupying all the space like in the following image
[image]

As you can see in the above picture the row with c5+ is unusually occupying lot of space

CSS for the Table

```
.clientTable {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
   height:75%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   width: 98%;
   margin-left:0;
   margin-right:100px;
    float: left;
   overflow:scroll;
}
table.clientTable thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}


table.clientTable td {
    padding: 1px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-color:#3C78B5;*/
    vertical-align: auto;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
    width: 120px; 
}
.clientTable th {
    padding: initial;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    width: initial;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px outset gray;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is it taking up 500 pixels?

Comment: Yeah almost but when I keep on adding more records to the table then the orange space goes down depending on the number of records

Comment: Okay, then; need to see more CSS. For the DIV, for example.

Comment: That is all the css I have for DIV

Comment: Oh, I had it backwards for some reason... I thought that was the CSS for the table. Oops! (That would have been the wrong place to put it, anyway!)

Comment: I have added CSS for my table in the question just in case

Comment: Try taking out the `float` and `overflow` on the `.clientTable`...

Comment: Yeah even the height and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change height to max-height. It's going grow to size if you don't specify and have the overflow as auto.

Comment: No, I want the table height to be fixed, that is the reason I have added scroll to the table. and same result even if I change the overflow property

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why do you have overflow-y:show instead of overflow-y:scroll ?

Comment: Well I did have overflow-y:scroll earlier but it didnt work. SO, I tried other property